# Не могу поставить Google play на genymotion - Android

Tags: java, android

Не могу поставить Google play на genymotion

Качаю гапс отсюда http://opengapps.org/. Ставил разные версии от pica до stock. Все равно при запуске появялется много ошибок типо приложение не вызвало ошибку com.gaps.... ну там разные быавют ошибки. И гугл плай, и гугл сервис и маил и все остальное.

Даже если быстро все выключить и открыть google play то в долю сек. есть шанс что можно ввести почту и пароль.Но после авторизации Google play просто не запускается. Я нажимаю на Google play он закрывается. И так всегда. В итоге даже обновить Gapps не могу.

Как быть что делать? Кто нибудь пробовал установить Gynemotion в 2017 году?. так как раньше год назад все было отлично.

Comment: Простите за глупость а зачем оно вм?) ведь апк и так скачать можно

Comment: Апк? ясно вы даже не понимаете о чем речь идет)